# About mxGraph: how can I first add Edge, and add my own custom attribute, then add to the graph?

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

Because I register a listener about the CELL_ADD to justify when I add two different types of edges, I deal with them in different ways.
But the problem is I failed to add the edge after I change my method to "add edge" action"

**HERE IS MY FIRST successful version :**

`graph.insertEdge(parent, null, '', defiVertex, outVertex);`

**HERE IS MY WANTED NEW VERSION but failed:**

```
 edge.edge = true;
 edge.type = AUTO_INSERT_EDGE;
 graph.addEdge(edge);
```

THANK FOR HELP!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but why don't you override the addListener function? In there, you can retrieve the changes, and if the name is mxTerminalChange you know you are adding/modifying an edge:

```
model.addListener(mx.mxEvent.CHANGE, function(sender, evt) {
    var changes = evt.getProperty('edit').changes;
    if (changes[i].constructor.name ==  "mxTerminalChange") {
        // Manage the add of a new connection
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Yes I have add the "CELLS_ADDED" listener to listener to the edge, but there are 2 situations in my case I need to recognize one of the two to do some change so I want to add a prototype(attribute) to all the edges when instructor them to help me decide whether I should do some changes.

Answer (score 0):

I change another way to finish my problem which is use the vue data attribute to help me record the state of the two add edge situations: when the edge is add by code, `this.isAutoAdd = true`, when user create the edge, `this.isAutoAdd=false`,so when in the listener, I just need to determine whether "isAutoAdd" is false to call the change function.